# The Push-up Push Workout

Tags: push-ups

According to [Military.com](http://www.military.com/military-fitness/workouts/try-pushup-push-workout), a source that I actually trust, a good start would be a routine of 200 push-ups/a day (for people who, like me, can't perform more than 50 push-ups).

More exactly: in odd days, 200 pushups in as few sets as possible. In even days, 200 pushups throughout the day.

Isn't this way too much? Isn't that already slipping into the unhealthy territory and it's a recipe for lesions?

Comment: One who can dedicate his time and will at doing 200 push-ups a day could dedicates himself to a more complete workout

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y53rXo2LT2s

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, if you can do 50 pushups in a row, you're due for some added resistance. The key to progress is overloading, and that can be done either with

- volume (doing more reps/sets), which you've accomplished
- intensity (using more weight), which is the second piece of this puzzle you're trying to complete

Also, you're right to be concerned, not just about lesions and tendonitis, but also about the effect on your body from doing ONLY pushups. What do you think is going to happen when you have a big chest? That the rest of your body is going to look equally good? No! It's going to look weird, and you're going to develop imbalances which, around your core, means chronic neck/back problems.

If you push, you also need to pull. And if you're working your upper body, you need to work your lower body too.

Don't neglect anything! If you have the time to do 200 pushups, try instead to do a total of 100 pushups with more weight instead, and spend the rest of the time doing pullups and squats. Then you have something that's starting to look like a more well-rounded routine!

Comment: If you're doing them right you shouldn't develop "core imbalances" to any significant degree-you're also planking the entire time, one of the better core exercises. Adding a pull component and legs, sure. But a regime consisting of pull ups, push-ups, and squats ain't all that bad.

Comment: "But a regime consisting of pull ups, push-ups, and squats ain't all that bad." - Yeah, that was kind of what I said in the last sentence there.

Comment: My issue is with the notion that 200 push-ups will cause physical problems. I was agreeing with you regarding variety, which is why I said "but" and agreed with you. But ok.